Debian wakes up when manually suspended AND when the lid closes
I'm currently facing an issue with my Lenovo E14 on Debian Bookworm.
When I close its lid, the system suspends itself, just like it's supposed to. When I open it, the system wakes up.
But whenever I change something on the computer, like plugging or unplugging a USB peripheral, or even when I close the lid (which is my biggest issue here), it wakes up!
I can reproduce it by :

manually suspend the computer
close the lid of the computer
it wakes up

Any idea? Thanks so much in advance! :)

Turns out UEFI update fixed that
